# How to start a Flatpak app minimized to tray in 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, flatpak

I can start a Flatpak app on login, but I would like to start it minimized to the tray

```
flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop --hidden
```

or

```
flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop --background
```

or

```
flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop --start-in-tray
```

doesn't work - any suggestions?

Comment: That will fully depend on whether the application provides an option to start it minimized. You will need to consult the documentation. There is no universal method, except perhaps on Xorg with a tool like devilspie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often find what parameters/arguments an app has available by running it with `--help` appended. In your case, it would be `flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop --help`. The displayed output does not mention any options for running it minimized:

```
[2:0803/104801.302388:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
10:48:02.042 › [DownloadsManager] init { 'this.json': {}, validatedJSON: {} }
10:48:02.049 › [DownloadsManager] saveAll
10:48:02.050 › [MainWindow] Can't send update-downloads-dropdown, will retry
10:48:02.051 › [DownloadsManager] checkForDeletedFiles
Options:
  -d, --dataDir         Set the path to where user data is stored.      [string]
  -p, --disableDevMode  Disable development mode. Allows for testing as if it
                        was Production.                                [boolean]
  -f, --fullscreen      Opens the application in fullscreen mode.      [boolean]
      --version         Show version number                            [boolean]
      --help            Show help                                      [boolean]
```

#### Option 1:

1. Launch the app
2. Menu ( ⋮ three vertical dots) > File > Settings
3. Toggle on "Launch app minimized"

From now on, every time you launch Mattermost, the window will not appear.

#### Option 2:

1. Go to the app's [Github project](https://github.com/flathub/com.mattermost.Desktop)
2. Find the Issues section
3. Put some effort into finding an existing topic about a feature request for having a CLI parameter/argument to launch the app in the background/tray.

- If you *can* find one, kindly express interest and see if you can help things move along.
- If you *can't* find an existing discussion, make one - describe clearly and in a non-demanding way (because often people are giving away their personal time to make your software better) what change you would hope to see.

It might take days or months (probably not years - since this should probably be a small change) but eventually you should eventually see a CLI option (as described in your question) appear in the app. Comments on the issue you opened or followed on Github will inform you of any progress. Note that it might take some for the code updates to reach the flatpak app.

Answer (score 3):

For me the command that works for starting Transmission minimized to tray is:

```
flatpak run com.transmissionbt.Transmission -m
```

My OS is Fedora 36 with GNOME though, so you might want to change the `com.transmissionbt.Transmission` part to match your system. I guess the `flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop -m` should work for you.

Comment: Firstly, Flatpak is designed to be relatively independent of the host OS and its packages. Secondly, Transmission happens to have that parameter, whilst Mattermost doesn't - at least as much as can be learned from running `flatpak run com.mattermost.Desktop --help`.